# How to store API responses of arbitrary structure in DynamoDB

Tags: mongodb, database-design, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

If I was to hypothetically build an app that received user input and then made an API request based on that input, then I wanted to store that user input along with the API JSON response, which could be of any arbitrary structure, in a DynamoDB. What would be the best practice from a design perspective?

In this situation I just need to keep the response data I do not need to query against it or anything.

**User** -> input { age: 23 } -> **MyApp** -> POST { user_age: 23 } -> **AnAPI** -> Response {birth_year: 1994, ....: {...}} -> **MyApp** -> **DynamoDB**

My initial idea would be to store a document that looks like this:

```
{
    user_name: 'anthony',
    age: '23',
    api_response: "JSON ENCODED STRING"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

DynamoDB also has a map type so you could just store the API JSON response in that